# javascript charting - nvd3 line chart with two Y-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Can anyone please suggest me a way to assign two Y-axis to a nvd3 line chart ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used `multiChart` of `nvd3` and customized it with minimal effort to achieve this.

Comment: I simply want the same y-axis on both sides of my chart for easy reading when the chart is quite wide. Is there a way to actually use lineChart and add a second axis while only using one data series?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the `linePlusBarChart` example from `nvd3` examples.